# Change media volumn while play music

Tags: android, android-videoview

I use below call to play music:

```
vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.screen_audio);
Uri music = Uri.parse(path);
vv.setVideoURI(music);
vv.start();
```

But when I playing, the volumn_up and volumn_down button can not press.
How can modify it to change the media volumn?

Comment: why you used VideoView to simply play music?

Comment: I try to play music and video and the same activity. But if play video the volumn can be press.

Comment: where is the code for your volume buttons? are you using any?or is it showing some error?

Comment: I did not use any volume buttons code. It also not show any error in Logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use controls to change the volume. Check below example to know about it.

[Implement a SeekBar to control the volume of Video Player](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/12/implement-seekbar-to-control-volume-of.html)